# How to restart a NativeProcess in adobe air desktop application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

I am running a .net .exe file from our adobe air application. The .exe file receive different parameters. So when I have to send new parameters I  stop the process and start again with new parameters. I am using exit() method of `NativeProcess` but when I start again the exe it give me

> Error: Error #3213: Cannot perform operation on a NativeProcess that is already running.
>    at Error$/throwError()
>    at flash.desktop::NativeProcess/start()

I have initialized nativeProcess as static variable:

```
public  static var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
public static var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
```

Then on a click event I have called the exe file

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
file = file.resolvePath("C:\\somepath.exe");
var ar:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
ar.push("0");
ar.push("C:\\temp\\APIData.xml");

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = ar;
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

This runs the code absolutely fine. On another click event I call

```
process.exit()
```

and then again run the exe

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory;
file = file.resolvePath("C:\\somepath.exe");
var ar:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
ar.push("1");
ar.push("C:\\temp\\APIData.xml");

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = ar;
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

But on this other click event I get the error of NativeProcess already running. Can some one help me what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you restart the process right after the exit it might be that the exit takes a bit longer and the process did not "exited" yet.

Try to listen for the exit event that is dispatched when the process have really ended and then restart the process:

```
process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onProcessExit);

private function onProcessExit(e:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
{
    // restart your process from here
}
```

When you call exit() it is not guaranteed that the process will end as it is happening outside of the flash scope. As a last resort you could try to force the process to exit:

```
process.exit(true);
```